# Are there female djinn?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, monsters, lore

I've been writing my back story for one of my characters who is an Air Genasi, and I was thinking of making the mother of my character the djinni, but I can't find any literature that references a female genie.

Can genies be female or male, or are they both? Although I am running 5th Edition, information from earlier editions would still be helpful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**

Support for your plan is right there in the core rules, MM (p.141):

> A genie usually retains no connection to the soul
>   that gave it form. That life force is a building block that
>   determines the genie's form and **apparent gender**, as
>   well as one or two key personality traits. Although they
>   resemble humanoid beings, genies are elemental spirits
>   given physical form. They don't mate with other genies
>   or produce genie offspring, as all new genies are born
>   out of the same mysterious fusion of spirit energy and
>   elemental power. **A genie with a stronger connection
>   to its mortal soul might choose to sire a child with a
>   mortal, although such offspring are rare.**